# Grouped .className + media query?

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries

Due an effect that splits the page and lets resize one of the containers. I have to add more styles for the responsive, So I add to this resizable container a class representing my current breakpoint (xs,sm,md,lg)

Like this

```
if ( ui.position.left <= 480 ) { /* It represent it's width, I am using this as the drag function of draggable */
                clase = 'xs';
            } else if ( ui.position.left <= 768 ) {
                clase = 'sm';
            } else if ( ui.position.left <= 992 ) {
                clase = 'md';
            } else {
                clase = 'lg';
            }
       $('.element').removeClass('xs sm md lg').addClass(clase);
```

for example:

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
  h2 {
    font-size:12px;
  }
}
```

and I now have to add:

```
   .xs h2 {
     font-size:12px
   }
```

Is there any way not to have to duplicate the styles? (I have several blocks)

Something like this that I won't work

```
.xs, @media (max-width:320px) {
   h2 {
     font-size: 12px
   }
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't possible.

Comment: I figured.. stil needed to ask, And with javascript?

Comment: If you care about simplifying your CSS files, then use LESS or SCSS. Using JavaScript is a bad idea for this.

Comment: Not sure what JS would give you. You'd still be writing CSS even if it's with JS. This is where pre-processors like SASS/LESS will help.

Comment: I tagged the question #compass, so I am using scss..

Comment: Maybe you should try BEM || SMACSS || OOCSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postcss and plugin https://github.com/hail2u/node-css-mqpacker. This easy and work fine. You can use postcss with SCSS.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @Paulie_D okey, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When using media queries, you usually have a global default, and then you override the default in the query, if a certain predicate is true (e.g. window with is less than 320px).

In your example, you would like to use the same value as the global default and the overridden value in the media query. IMHO this makes no sense whatsoever.